# How do I ensure accurate implementation of app UI design?

Tags: android, user-interface

### TL;DR

How to make sure that the UI design is pixel-perfectly implemented by the developers?

### Explanation

Our design team creates mockups for our Android apps. These mockups are usually in `.PSD` (Photoshop document) format, and sometimes hosted online for additional features like comments or versioning.

Once the design starts getting implemented by the development team, we face some accuracy and precision issues. Ensuring pixel-perfect implementation of design is a big headache.

Usually what we do, is that we use Photoshop to compare the implemented view and the mockup. That highlights the differences, but takes a lot of time.

Any better way for the developers? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to automate this process as some sort of testing strategy?

Comment: Yeah that would be awesome! Just stumbled upon this thing: https://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Zeplin.io](http://zeplin.io) in the past which works pretty well. Though this does depend heavily on your definition of "pixel perfect". On Android there are over 2,000 unique screen sizes so some areas (such as alignment padding/margin) should be easy to get exactly what you want, others not so much (e.g. 5 toolbar icons may not be possible on some devices)

Comment: What do you do for image sizes?  I have been following material design using the 1, x1.5, x2, x3 rule and making four sizes for each image, but some smaller screens still cut images or overlap because the device is too small.

Comment: This depends on what you mean:
Pictures -> you should set the scale type appropriately (center, center_inside, fit_center, etc.)
Icons -> the container should always be the correct size (48dp) with the icon base size (mdpi) being 48px (google has more information at https://material.google.com/style/icons.html) though I would also recommend VectorDrawables (support)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't messed with the scale type yet.  Should I be making four sizes of each picture as well (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi)?  Or is that just for image buttons and icons?

Comment: Typically that is just for icons, though there are some cases it *could* be useful (e.g. splashcreen images) though that is a good way to increase APK size quickly.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you for the input!